# Single-word replacement for "To be replaced"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word to describe an old item that is soon to be replaced.

Temporary was the first thing that came to mind, but it didn't seem to fit in context as the old object has been there for a long time already so is hardly an interim substitute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might consider *obsolescent* or *obsolete*.

> **obsolescent** *adjective* [[ODO]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/obsolescent)
>   becoming obsolete:
>   *obsolescent equipment*
>
> **obsolete** *adjective* [[ODO]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/obsolete)
>   no longer produced or used; out of date:
>   *the disposal of old and obsolete machinery*

If it's simply to be replaced due to wear-and-tear, and its replacement is essentially the same, then ***worn out*** or the more jargon-ish *"end of life"* might be better.

Comment: +1. I suppose if it wasn't obsolete, but wasn't worn-out either, one could also address whatever reason one had for the replacement, "the slower RAM has not yet been replaced", "the less stylish window-frame is still in place" or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider **[well worn](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/well-worn?q=well-worn)** (or *well-worn*)

> showing the signs of extensive use or wear:
>   *a well-worn leather armchair*

Note that impending replacement is not necessarily implied.

Answer (score -1):

***Dispensable***, ***Disposable***

[source](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=dispensable+meaning&oq=dispensable+&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j69i60j0l2j69i60j0.9038j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Sources should be direct links to authoritative sources, not just links to a Google search. In addition, neither _dispensable_ nor _disposable_ describe something that is about to be replaced: they describe something that _can_ be replaced, whether it’s about to be or not.